# Positioning label on CPTBarPlot (Core-Plot)

Tags: ios, position, label, core-plot, cptbarplot

I am trying to change default position of labels in Bar chart with Core-Plot.
I am using this method:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

And I return:

```
return textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"2222" style:textStyle];
```

I get this result:

[image]

But I want to appear as follows:

[image]

Any idea? I tried to find answer on documentation, but I has been impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a negative `labelOffset` for the bar plot. The default is +10 which puts the labels 10 pixels above the bars. This property is inherited from `CPTPlot` so it works for all plot types, although the default value and behavior varies somewhat.

Comment: @Eric Skroch Is there any way to set different labelOffset of cptbarplots in a plot? I want to show label exactly in the center of CPTBarplot.

Comment: @HinataHyuga No. Instead of data labels, use a plot space annotation with a `CPTTextLayer` as its content and center it on the bar.

Comment: @EricSkroch is there a way to have it so that its at the axis end and not the tip of the bar end?